# How to set execution path in MbUnit?

Tags: unit-testing, mbunit

Is there any way to set an execution path for the tested DLL so it can find resource folders when MbUnit copy files into a temporary folder without using Dependency Injection?

Trying to put these extra files as content and set behaviour to copy did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running these tests from the command-line, NAnt or MSBuild you can specify the application base directory and working directory arguments.

There are similar mechanisms available using Gallio Icarus or the ReSharper integration.